# Add Some custom Text at the place where value is null in the join?

Tags: mysql, join

I want to join two table in such away that If there is no value against first table entry in the second table then it should fetch that row but insert some custom text in that row.
Is there any possibility of achieving this any idea would be appreciated.
For Example
Table 1 have Columns A(primary key), B, C and Table 2 have Columns D(Primcary key), A(foreign key), E;
I want Result Like this
[image]

Comment: Please add some data example and expected result

Comment: @ErgestBasha check now

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Are you looking for `COALESCE(...)` or `IFNULL(...)`?

Comment: I am looking for IFNULL(.....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [case expression](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/).

Consider the following data which can be found on [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O1b7PaBX)

```
create table table1(
  A varchar(10),
  B varchar(10),
  C varchar(10) ) ;
  
create table table2(
  D varchar(10),
  A varchar(10) ) ;  
  
insert into table1 values
('val','val','val');

insert into table2 values
(null,'val');
```

Query,

```
select t1.A,
       t1.B,
       t1.C,
       case when t2.D is null then 'Add some text' end as D
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1 using(A);
```

Note. You need to use left join to get the null results from the table2

Comment: `IFNULL(t2.D, 'Replacement text')` is way more convenient